# How is the right syntax for selecting values from MySQL in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table created with the next values

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (TWEET_ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, RETWEETS INT, FAVORITES INT, HASHTAG VARCHAR(255))
```

I've already inserted values into the table, and when i do the the next query from MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE TWEET_ID=1300170783138942978
```

i get the actual values inside the table.

On the other hand, when i run exactly the same query from python using:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE TWEET_ID=1300170783138942978')
```

I get a None value as return

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. What are you printing to get `None`?

Comment: Would be also nice to see if you do any error checking in your code. The problem may very well be in other parts of your code!

Comment: `execute()` will return `None`. Iterate the cursor or use one of the [`fetch*()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) methods to get results.

Comment: Thank you Klaus, I'm a little bit of a noob in SQL and i didn't even know the existence of fetch*() methods. I executed my statement, and then captured the value using cursor.fetchone()

Comment: A tutorial might come in handy